# Nativescript 6 - environment specific files not working

Tags: nativescript

I just recently migrated my app to NS 6 and I noticed that the environment specific files are not processed properly.

E.g. I have settings.debug.json and settings.release.json.  In code, I reference them as **import * as settings from '/settings.json'** .  In NS < 6, this used to work, but now I get an error that that settings.json does not exist.

I have very limited experience with Webpack.  Is there a setting I need to configure there for this to work?

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "<app>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "<id>",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "description": "",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.2",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.3.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.4.0",
    "nativescript-local-notifications": "3.1.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.2",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "readme": "",
  "author": ""
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure it's not supported by {N} CLI, are you using any plugin / hook? If then the hook has to be modified to support v6.x, refer the migration document.

Comment: Yes,  I am using several plugins.  I will check the documentation and will report back.

Comment: I meant, are you using any plugin what will help you to copy environment specific files as it's not a feature out of the box.

Comment: got you. In previous versions this was working by default, so I am not using any plugins.

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally load the files using the `TNS_ENV` variable.

```
const settings = TNS_ENV !== 'production' ? require('./settings.debug.json') : require('./settings.release.json')
```

Comment: Do I need to import it from somewhere?

Comment: `require('./settings.debug.json')` is the equivalent of your original import statement.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant TNS_ENV.  It does not exist out of the box.  How do I define it.

Comment: It should already be defined in your `webpack.config.js`.

`plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
    "TNS_ENV": JSON.stringify(mode),
    "process": "global.process"
  }),
]`